# IE6 Z-Index Difference Between 2 Servers

Tags: coldfusion, iis-6, internet-explorer-6, load-balancing, z-index

So, I have 2 servers that serve pages.  I am running ColdFusion on Windows Server 2003 with IIS6.  I created the site and synchronized the files between the 2 servers.  In the right hand side of my site is a popup div for the search.  On Server1 in IE6, this div works perfectly, on server 2 it gets cut off.  Due to the synchronization software used, I cannot have different files on the two servers.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Just FYI, history is kept so even if you remove the URLs with an edit, they can still be found. Something to keep in mind in the future if you don't want something to be listed here permanently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out!  It seems that 2 image files, for some reason, didn't have read permissions on them on the second server:

/images/search_04_drop_04-ie6.png
/images/search_jason_04-ie6.png

updated the permissions and it started working.

Thanks for all of your help in this.

Answer (score 3):

Your IE6 stylesheet if failing to load for the second site.

This URL works:
http://www.sdccc.org:81/styles/03-ie6-fix.css

This URL doesn't:
http://www.sdccc.org:82/styles/03-ie6-fix.css

Oddly, this only appears to occur in IE itself - verifying the links above in Chrome and both of them work.

***Update:***
The port 82 server is returning **Content-Encoding: gzip** and **Vary: Accept-Encoding** headers - the port 81 server is not.

I suspect this is a bug with IE not accepting the gzipped content?

Comment: that's odd that the second stylesheet didnt work for you.  I am getting it in IE6 for both URLs and they look identical.

Comment: See my update - I think there may be a bug with IE6/gzip causing the second URL to fail?
You might want to verify that both servers have the same gzip settings...

Comment: I changed the compression on the servers to match.  I also compared the metabase files on both servers and they are identical with the exception of the ACLs.  The problem still exists.

Comment: Yep, I can get the CSS files for both servers now.

I'm getting Google Analytics related JS errors - might not be connected, but worth temporarily removing the GA to rule it out?

Comment: sorry it so long to get back to you, i tired removing the GA and it had no affect.  this is really mind bottling

Answer (score 1):

Two equal documents in the same browser has to produce the same page:

As I can see the document produced by each servers are practically the same, except for the CSS stylesheet:

```
<LINK href="./sd81_files/01-ejungle.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and

```
<LINK href="http://www.sdccc.org:82/styles/01-ejungle.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Yes, you can say that the files are the same, but when I saved the files into my computer, the second one did not arrive. Check the link and try again.

Comment: I have no idea how this came up for you.  The sd81_files doesnt even exist on my server